# Generar números aleatorios dentro de un while

Tags: c, while, random

buenos días estoy en un gran problema intentando crear un bucle que se se repita 10 veces y en cada repetición me salga un numero diferente entre 1 y 10, la cosa es que en cada repetición me sale el mismo numero.

```
int main()
{
    int numeroRAN,repeticion;
    
    repeticion=1;
    
    while(repeticion<10){
        
    srand(time(NULL));
    numeroRAN=1+rand() %10;
    
    printf ("%d\n",numeroRAN);
    
    repeticion++;
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias cosas que debes considerar:

- El código se ejecuta completamente en una fracción de segundo.
- [`time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) devuelve un número entero que representa el tiempo en segundos (tiempo unix).

Dado el punto anterior, es de esperar que `time()` devuelva el mismo número.

- `srand()` recibe una "semilla" para generar los números.

[La documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/num%C3%A9rico/ransom/srand) dice que cada vez que se establece una nueva semilla (independientemente de si es igual), `srand` producirá la misma secuencia.

Por lo tanto, como la semilla es la misma, y esta es reestablecida constantemente, obtienes el mismo resultado.

---

La forma de que el resultado difiera es que alguno de los factores que condicionan el resultado cambie.

Por ejemplo:

- La más sencilla, dejar de llamar `srand` constantemente.

  ```
  // En este caso se soluciona llamándolo una vez al inicio.
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      int numeroRAN = 1 + rand() % 10;
      printf("%d\n", numeroRAN);
  }
  ```
- Dar una seed diferente cada vez (una solución cuestionable).

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      srand(time(i));
      int numeroRAN = 1 + rand() % 10;
      printf("%d\n", numeroRAN);
  }
  ```