# No sé como empezar a programar en C++

Tags: c++, funciones, punteros

Me han dejado este ejercicio, pero no sé como empezar a realizarlo y no tengo casos de prueba ni ejemplos. Creo que podría usar punteros. Pero no estoy empapada del todo.

> Programe la colisión entre estos 4 planetas. Las colisiones son por pares de planetas. Cualquier planeta puede colisionar con otro, si la distancia entre ellos (aleatorio entre 0 y 30) es menor a 0.5. No necesita considerar distancias reales entre planetas, sino usar un numero random para decidir si hay colisión.
> Luego de la colisión, el planeta más pesado sobrevive, y se le suma la mitad de la masa del otro planeta (hay perdida de masa por la colisión). Además, su diámetro se duplica.

Tomé como datos, los siguientes pesos y diámetros, en unidades de masa/diámetro terrestre ( porque según yo son los más famosos):

Mercurio (0.05 masa terrestre, diámetro 0.4)

Venus (0.8 masa terrestre, diámetro 0.9)

Tierra (1 masa terrestre, diámetro 1)

Marte (0.1 masa terrestre, diámetro 0.5)

tengo esta parte del código que hice, pero no logro encontrar una forma de empezar...

```
/*. sistema solar.*/
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int A,B,planetas;
  cout <<"Elegir los planetas a colisionar: "<<endl;
  cout<<"1) marte"<<endl;
  cout<<"2) tierra"<<endl;
  cout<<"3) mercurio"<<endl;
  cout<<"4) venus"<<endl;
  cin>>planetas;
  if tierra distancia > 0.5{
    
  }
  
  
}

void distancia(){
  int distancia; 
  srand(time(NULL));
  num=rand()%31;
  return distancia;
}
void tierra(){
  int masa = 1;
  int diametro = 1
  while diametro >
}
```

Comment: creo que sería necesario un switch para esos casos...

Comment: Bienvenida, el formato que habías elegido está pensado para HTML, CSS y Javascript y permite ejecutar ese código. No funciona con C++.

Comment: Hol4, al parecer ese ejercicio es de un juego o algo parecido? porque si es así, te podría interesar ver este vídeo donde explica muy bien las trayectoria(coordenadas) y las colisiones.
del juego asteroid. aun que no es lo mismo pero te podría llevar por buen camino [Link Video] https://youtu.be/p9uG2Ze7D7c "Programación de Juegos C++ - Parte 11: Final! - Colisión Bala-Asteroide"

Comment: Sobre la sintaxis: luego de escribir `if`, `for`, `while` y `switch` debes poner los parámetros que requiera la estructura de control entre paréntesis. Por ejemplo, después del `if` pondrías una condición: `if (edad > 10) { ... }`. Sobre el programa: cuando lo ejecutes `rand` producirá los mismos números por razones que expliqué en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/542253/169744).

Answer (score 1):

```
//codigo

#include <stdio.h>        
#include <windows.h>          
#include <conio.h>         
#include <stdlib.h>        
#include <list>        

using namespace std;

#define ARRIBA 72
#define IZQUIERDA 75
#define DERECHA 77
#define ABAJO 80



void situarCursor(int x, int y)
{
 HANDLE hCon;
 hCon=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);        
 COORD cPunto;
  cPunto.X=x;
  cPunto.Y=y;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon,cPunto);
 }

  void ocultarCursor()
 {
 HANDLE hCon;
 hCon=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cInfo;
 cInfo.dwSize=2;
 cInfo.bVisible=FALSE;
 SetConsoleCursorInfo(hCon,&cInfo);
 }
  void pintarLimites()
 {
 for(int i=2; i<78;i++)
 {
  situarCursor(i,2); printf("%c",205);
  situarCursor(i,33); printf("%c",205);
 }
 for(int i=3; i<33;i++)
 {
  situarCursor(2,i); printf("%c",186);
  situarCursor(77,i); printf("%c",186);
 }
  situarCursor(2,2); printf("%c",201);
  situarCursor(2,33); printf("%c",200);
  situarCursor(77,2); printf("%c",187);
  situarCursor(77,33); printf("%c",188);
 }

 class NAVE
{
 int x,y;
 int corazones;
 int vidas;
 public:
  NAVE(int _x, int _y, int _corazones, int 
 _vidas):x(_x),y(_y), corazones(_corazones), 
  vidas(_vidas){}
  void pintar();
  void borrar();
  void mover();
  void pintarCorazones();
  void morir();
  void restarCorazon(){corazones--;}
  int X(){return x;}
  int Y(){return y;}
  int VIDAS(){return vidas;}
};

void NAVE::pintar()
{
  situarCursor(x,y);printf("  %c",30);
  situarCursor(x,y+1);printf(" %c%c%c",40,207,41);
  situarCursor(x,y+2);printf("%c%c %c%c",30,190,190,30);
}
void NAVE::borrar()
{
 situarCursor(x,y);printf("          ");
 situarCursor(x,y+1);printf("          ");
 situarCursor(x,y+2);printf("          ");
}

void NAVE::mover()
{
 if(kbhit())
  {
   char tecla=getch();
   borrar();
   if(tecla==IZQUIERDA && x>3){x--;}
   if(tecla==DERECHA && x+6<78){x++;}
   if(tecla==ARRIBA && y>3){y--;}
   if(tecla==ABAJO && y+3<33){y++;}
   pintar();

  }
}

void NAVE::pintarCorazones()
{

 situarCursor(50,1);
 printf("Vidas: %d", vidas);


 situarCursor(64,1);
 printf("Salud");
 situarCursor(70,1);
 printf("       ");
 for(int i=0; i<corazones;i++)
 {
   situarCursor(70+i,1);
   printf("%c",3);
 }

 }

 void NAVE::morir()
 {
   if(corazones==0)
 {
   borrar();
  situarCursor(x,y);   printf("   **   ");
  situarCursor(x,y+1); printf("  ***  ");
  situarCursor(x,y+2); printf("   **   ");
  Sleep(200);
  borrar();
  situarCursor(x,y);   printf(" * ** * ");
  situarCursor(x,y+1); printf("* *** *");
  situarCursor(x,y+2); printf("* ** *");
  Sleep(200);
   borrar();
   vidas--;
   corazones=3;
   pintarCorazones();
   pintar();
 }
}

class AST
{
 int x,y;
public:
 AST(int _x, int _y):x(_x),y(_y){}
 void pintar();
 void mover();
 void choque(class NAVE &N);
 int X(){return x;}
 int Y(){return y;}
};

void AST::choque(class NAVE &N)
{
 if(x>=N.X() && x<= N.X()+5 && y>=N.Y() && y<=N.Y()+2)
 {
  N.restarCorazon();
  N.pintar();
  N.pintarCorazones();
  x=rand()%71+4;
  y=4;
 }
}

 void AST::pintar()
{
 situarCursor(x,y);printf("%c",184);

}
void AST::mover()
{
 situarCursor(x,y);printf(" ");
 y++;
 if(y>32)
 {
  x=rand()%71+4;
  y=4;
 }
 pintar();
}

class BALA
{
 int x,y;
public:
 BALA(int _x, int _y):x(_x),y(_y){}
 void mover();
 bool fuera();
 int X(){return x;}
 int Y(){return y;}

 };

void BALA::mover()
{
 situarCursor(x,y); printf(" ");
 if(y>3){y--;}
 situarCursor(x,y); printf("*");
}

bool BALA::fuera()
 {
 if(y==3)
 {
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

int main()
{
 int puntos=0;
 pintarLimites();
 ocultarCursor();
 NAVE N(38,30,3,5);
 N.pintar();
 N.pintarCorazones();

 list<AST*> A;
 list<AST*>::iterator Ait;

 for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
 {
  A.push_back(new AST(rand()%75+3, rand()%5+4));
 }

 list<BALA*> B;
 list<BALA*>::iterator it;

 bool game_over=false;
 while (!game_over)
 {

  situarCursor(4,2); printf("Puntos: %d",puntos);

  if(kbhit())
  {
   char tecla=getch();
   if(tecla=='c')
   {
    B.push_back(new BALA(N.X()+2,N.Y()-1));
   }
  }

  for(it=B.begin(); it!=B.end();)
  {
   (*it)->mover();
   if((*it)->fuera())
  {
    situarCursor((*it)>X(),(*it)>Y());
    printf(" ");
    delete(*it); 
    it=B.erase(it);
   }
   else it++;

  }


  for(Ait=A.begin(); Ait!=A.end(); Ait++ )
  {
   (*Ait)->mover();
   (*Ait)->choque(N);
  }

  //detectar colisiones entre bala y asteroides
  for(Ait=A.begin(); Ait!=A.end();Ait++)
  {
   for(it=B.begin(); it!=B.end(); )
   {
    if((*Ait)>X()==(*it)>X() && ( (*Ait)>Y()+1==(*it)>Y() 
|| 
    (*Ait)>Y()==(*it)>Y()))
    {
     situarCursor((*it)>X(),(*it)>Y());printf(" ");
     delete(*it); 
     it=B.erase(it);
 
     A.push_back(new AST(rand()%75,3));
     situarCursor((*Ait)>X(),(*Ait)>Y());printf(" ");
     delete(*Ait); 
     Ait=A.erase(Ait);
     puntos+=5;

    }
    else
    {
     it++;
    }
   }

  }

  if(N.VIDAS()==0)
  {
   game_over=true;
  }

  N.morir();
  N.mover();
  Sleep(30);

 }

    return 0;
 }
```